# How to add a check box column in Janus gridEX

Tags: c#, janus, gridex

I have a Janus GridEX that loaded from DataTable in SQL database, It have 8 column in my Grid. Now I want to add check box column list and ability to select multiple rows.
I'll be appreciate if some one help!

Answer (score 1):

This is VB.NET code.
    Imports Janus.Windows.GridEX

```
    grdEmail.RootTable.Columns("receive_email").ColumnType = ColumnType.CheckBox
    grdEmail.RootTable.Columns("receive_email").EditType = EditType.CheckBox
    grdEmail.RootTable.Columns("receive_email").CheckBoxTrueValue = "Yes"
    grdEmail.RootTable.Columns("receive_email").CheckBoxFalseValue = "No"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this example [Janus GridEX Example](http://www.doozer.com/developer-exchange/janus-gridex) you can do like this:

```
column.EditType = EditType.CheckBox;
```

To enhance the multiple selection, try this way:

```
gridEX1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultipleSelection;
```